# Perl system call to jar file failing in cron

Tags: java, perl, cron

I am trying to execute a perl script via a cron job that uses the system command to execute a java wrapper for boilerpipe.  It fails when executed via cron.  The script (simplified) is

```
my $link = "http://foo.bar"; # with a real link
my $cmdstring = 'java -jar boilerpipe-wrapper.jar url '.$link.' out.txt';
my $result = system($cmdstring);
if ($? == -1) {
    print LOG "failed to execute system command: $!\n";
    die;
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf LOG "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
    die;
}
else {
    printf LOG "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
    die;
}
```

The die commands are in there for debugging purposes.  What appears in LOG is

```
child exited with value 1
```

The crontab line is

```
24 7 * * * perl /home/retrievetext.pl >> /home/cron-msgs 2>&1
```

What appears in cron-msgs is

```
Error: unable to access jarfile boilerpipe-wrapper.jar
Died at /home/retrievetext.pl line 15
```

The ls -la for boilerpipe-wrapper.jar is

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steve sudo 1945275 Apr 29 03:53 boilerpipe-wrapper.jar
```

The Perl script and the system call work as expected when executed from the terminal.  Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: When running something under `cron` the environment is usually _very_ limited. In your case `boilerpipe-wrapper.jar` isn't found by `java` (I think). Presumably the `CLASSPATH` isn't set? Try `24 7 * * * (env; perl /home/retrievetext.pl) >> /home/cron-msgs 2>&1` to see cron's environment when it invokes your script.

Comment: Also: _Whose cronjob is that?_ Yours? or e.g. root's?

Comment: Based on your hunch that the .jar wasn't being found, I did some searching around and found that I needed to specify the full path to the jar file in the perl script.  I guess I should have known that cron wouldn't know what path the perl script was in :-/  It's working now.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait...I spoke too soon.  It appeared to run but the .jar still failed.  Running the cron as you specified above the env shows HOME = /root, LOGNAME = root, PATH = /usr/bin:/bin, LANG=en_US.UTF-8, SHELL=/bin/sh,PWD=root.  So obviously root owns the cron job.  But I thought the jar world execute permissions would take care of that.

Comment: Well, `root` can execute your jar, but it still does so as user `root`, not as `steve`. Either drop the root's cronjob and re-install it as your own (steve's) OR change root's cronjob to `su - steve -c "perl /home/retrievetext.pl"`. I'd prefer a cronjob for `steve`. And don't worry: cronjobs are always a mess if not setup very precisely. ;-)